# I want to execute two simple input functions at the exact same time

Tags: c, multithreading, sendinput, conio

i'm new here and new in any other than C, too litle in C# and none of C++
I heard about C not being capable of multithreading, because it's read line by line, POSIX and stuff, but what i want is to run two input functions from C at the same time. Does not matter if I have to pick up a lot of libraries from C to C++ or whatever.

I was trying to execute this simple code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<conio.h>

// Display message until key is pressed.

// This structure will be used to create the keyboard and mouse
// input event

int main () {
    int x=1;
     
    INPUT ip,ip2,ip3;
    
    ip.type = 0;
    ip.mi.mouseData = XBUTTON1;
    ip.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    ip.mi.time = 0;


    ip2.type= 0;
    ip2.mi.mouseData=XBUTTON1;
    ip2.mi.dwFlags=MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    ip2.mi.time = 0;

    ip3.type= INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip3.ki.wVk= VK_RETURN;
    ip3.ki.dwFlags=0;
    ip3.ki.time=0;
   
    while(x=1){
        Sleep(5000);
        SendInput(1,&ip3,sizeof(ip3));
        SendInput(1,&ip,sizeof(ip));
        SendInput(1,&ip2,sizeof(ip2));
    }
}
```

What i really want is to synthesize a keyboard stroke enter and a left click press to be readed by my desktop at exactly same time. Does not necessary need to be this function at all.
How do I make this run at the SAME TIME? could you guys gimme a refreshed version of this simple code that could achieve that?

Comment: "I heard about C not being capable of multi thread" is not true, except in the sense that the C base language doesn't have threading support. C can use threads, but it requires a threading library, e.g. POSIX Threads or something from your host OS, like Windows.

Comment: That being said, you probably do not need threads here. If these run sequentially, there's likely a few nanoseconds of delay, so they're in effect simultaneous. If you need two functions to "run at the exact same time" that's not really practical, as it's very difficult to get two threads to run precisely at the same schedule. They can run "close enough" to not matter if you synchronize using semaphores and such, but most threading code is more concerned with executing in the *proper sequence* rather than *simultaneously*.

Comment: i would just edit to post about this POSIX STUFF TOO, but this was my introduction not my question sir. Could you gimme a delight of your knowledge in this primitive code of mine?

Comment: It would really help if you try and explain what you're trying to do, and what constraints you have, rather than jumping into the ins and outs of multi-threaded code, which is something that you **really want to avoid**, unless you have an actual concurrency issue due to having more than one CPU-bound operation.

Comment: You could also use `for(;;)` here to avoid the completely useless `x` variable.

Comment: The Windows application [receiving those `SendInput`ed events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) won't process them exactly simultaneously either; they go in a (fast-drained) queue on the other end. You could call `SendInputs` only once if you wanted, but as asked in comments: what are you actually aiming for, here?

Comment: '' If you need two functions to "run at the exact same time" that's what i want, is that possible in any kind of circunstace?

Comment: Does select do what you want?

Comment: ''The Windows application receiving those SendInputed events won't process them exactly simultaneously either; they go in a (fast-drained) queue on the other end. You could call SendInputs only once if you wanted, but as asked in comments: what are you actually aiming for, here? – 
AKX''     i was expecting to you guys gimme a version of this code that could be readed at same time, i do know that this code can't be readed at same time i know  about vectors too.

Comment: ''Does select do what you want? – stark''   And what this do?

Comment: It lets you wit for input from any of multiple sources.

Comment: @tadman, even the C base language has threading since C11, though it remains popular to use platform specific threading features instead.

Comment: When you say you want to run two input functions at once, do you mean `SendInput()` calls?  Or are you talking about *consuming* the input synthesized by the program in the question?  Or something else?

Comment: @JohnBollinger hi John, well if its possible to synthesize a keystroke and a mouse click in other ways that can achieve the goal of be readed and writed at same time, i'm thirsty to know your resolution.

Comment: @tadman Sorry bothering you again, but  its really that hard to simulate, sinthesize keystroke & left click or whatever its called at same time ? input functions was like my intro tryng to explain this.

Comment: "Same time" is misleading here. Do you mean "immediately following" or do you mean "simulate holding a key while clicking the mouse"?

Comment: I'm not sure "at the same time" even exists in the real world, given the finite speed of light and so on.  Perhaps it would be better to say "within 1 millisecond of each other" or something like that, instead?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, i quickly found a stuff called autoit that could synchronize (no mirror) the cursor of differents computer, so with only 1 its like impossible?

Comment: @tadman the second option "simulate holding a key while clicking the mouse" its like scam two thingsm stocking them then triggering together from two diffent sources like alternating current,  this is called "multi-Threads"? something like that can be only active  with more than 1 pc like autoit thing. Just thinking in a multiplayer game people doing diffrents stuff at same in only 1 game

Comment: @tadman The C language actually has thread support since 13 years back. They just added it too late when pthreads/CreateThread etc were already de facto standard, so nobody uses the standardized thread API.

Comment: @bilbo Can you elaborate on how this code is not simultaneous enough for your use case? As I said, the events won't be processed exactly simultaneously no matter what you do here. If you want to simulate holding a key while clicking the mouse, you need four events: key-down, mouse-down, mouse-up, key-up.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard about C not being capable of multithreading, because it's read line by line

That's just nonsense - C was probably the first ever programming language to use threads, by means of threading libraries. However, you do not necessarily need multi-threading for this - you can just tap into the window messages sent from the OS to the application.

What you can do in Windows is to compile your program as a Windows application with a `Wndproc` message callback function (check out Windows API beginner learning materials), then listen to for example `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` (left mouse button down) and `WM_KEYDOWN` (regular keyboard key down). You can record the last state of the mouse buttons/keyboard keys of interest in `static` variables, then check them both whenever either event happens.

Typically you do not use a console in such applications but Windows-specific `WinMain` which doesn't create a console (unless you ask for it manually).